# Segmentation fault after free(), what are the common causes for this?

Tags: c, free, segmentation-fault

I get a segmentation fault after `free`ing a certain pointer:

```
free(studentDB->name);
```

I can get its value without any errors or warnings:

```
printf("[DBG] studentDB->name: %s\n", studentDB->name);
```

However, as I said, the program crashes when I try to free it. What are the most common causes for a `free` command leading to a segmentation fault?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you didn't `malloc()` it, you can't `free()` it.  Where does `studentDB->name` come from?

Comment: Or you try to free it twice. More common, I think.

Comment: Spot on. It was a pointer, but I hadn't used `malloc` to allocate memory for it.

Answer (score 4):

You've probably either free()'ed it already, or overwritten the malloc info preceding the block with a buffer overrun

Comment: The bufferoverrun thing was what solved my issue, I didn't even looked for it cause there was no memory error until freeing.

Answer (score 3):

Usually heap corruption somewhere else in the program. The heap is usually continous and the heap manager surrounds heap blocks with headers to track the blocks- If you overwrite the header of the block, access to it is fine, but `free` is most likely to fail.

Answer (score 0):

A segfault from `free` can be caused by calling it on a pointer that was not allocated with `malloc`, or had been `free`'d already.

It would help if you posted the code where `studentDB->name` was allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Has `studentDB->name` being allocated previously? If you did not allocate memory for that field, chances are when you called `free`, you end up with a seg-fault! Please check on that field and make sure it has being `malloc`d or `strdup`d.

Or that there is a corruption elsewhere on the heap, that coincided with this as you rightly pointed out you can see the value of `name`...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Could also be that accessing the name member of the studentDB pointer is a segfault if studentDB is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

From manpage:

> free( ptr ) frees the memory space
>   pointed to by ptr, which must have
>   been returned by a previous call to
>   malloc(), calloc() or realloc().
>   Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already
>   been called before, undefined
>   behaviour occurs. If ptr is NULL, no
>   operation is performed.

One can also check:

1. Is studentDB a non-NULL pointer to a class/struct containing a member "name"?
2. Is the space pointed to by studentDB->name was returned by malloc/calloc/realloc?